# ETL Using SSIS vs .NET Executable

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Currently I have an ETL job that will transfer data between SQL Server database every X minutes. The ETL job is done via a .NET exe. Recently the client would want the data to more realtime-ish.

I has been exposed to the ideal of using SSIS to do the ETL job instead. As I know, SSIS is designed to operate in a batch mode. So the data readiness would almost be the same as using back the .NET executable?

What is the advantage of using SSIS? Is it able to optimize the ETL process to serve the near realtime requirement?

Comment: What volume of data in width and count? What kind of network latency? What hardware capabilities are available? Which buffers are available where? How many database servers are involved? Are there spike network shifts during the day? What level of realtime is expected? Which sizes of batches were tested? Without any idea about the answers to these questions there is simply not any chance to determine if SSIS is better or worse than the current job.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS offers components that are dedicated to extracting, transforming and loading data between different databases. On the functional side, a Batch developed in C# will not be too optimized in terms of execution time as ssis package. On the other hand SSIS packages are easier to integrate within SQL Server using SQL Server agent so you can schedule your jobs and see the execution logs of each package. 
We get the same issue for a customer need, so there are limitations for the batch when there is a lot of data to process but it also remains a solution for a data volume which is not substantial.